# About cluster points in a proof

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

I am reading in a proof, but there's only one part that I do not understand

> **Theorem**: Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$, let $z_1,z_2,\dots$ be a sequence of different points from $\Omega$ with no cluster point in $\Omega$, [...]
>
> **Proof**: Since the sequence $\{z_k\}$ does not cluster in $\Omega$, there exist $a\in \Omega$ and $r>0$ such that $B(a,r)$ does not intersect the set $\{z_k\}$. [...]

The definition of a cluster point is as follows

> Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{C}$, a point $a\in\mathbb{C}$ is called an cluster point of $A$ if $(B(a,r)\cap A)\setminus \{a\}\neq \emptyset$ for all $r>0$.

So, saying that $A$ has no cluster points, it must mean, by negating this definition that

> $$\forall a\in \mathbb{C}\exists r>0:(B(a,r)\cap A)\setminus \{a\}= \emptyset \tag{1}$$

I do not understand why the proof is true, and/or what is the connection between this and $(1)$?

Comment: Suppose for some $a$ that $B(a,{1 \over n})$ intersects the sequence. Then there must be a subsequence converging to $a$ which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Let's favor prose over notation.

*Definition*:  A point $c$ is a *cluster point* of a sequence $\{z_{k}\}_{k}$ if every neighborhood of $c$ contains a point of the sequence.

This definition implies: If $c$ is a cluster point of  $\{z_{k}\}_{k}$, then every neighborhood of $c$ contains infinitely many points of the sequence.

Now suppose $\{z_{k}\}_{k}$ has no cluster points in a set $\Omega$.  Pick any point $\omega$ in $\Omega$ and any neighborhood of $\omega$ in $\Omega$.  This neighborhood, then, contains at most finitely points of the sequence.  Therefore, we can find a ball $B(a, r)$ in that neighborhood that contains no points of the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\Omega$ is open in $\mathbb{C}$, it's uncountable, and hence we can choose a point $z$ not in our sequence $z_1,\cdots$. Now since $z$ isn't a cluster point of the sequence, there is some neighborhood $B(z,r)$ such that $B(z,r)\setminus \{z\}$ doesn't intersect our sequence. But $z$ doesn't either, so $B(z,r)$ doesn't intersect the sequence, as desired.

Comment: "... and hence we can choose a point $z$ not in our sequence ..." Why is it a "hence"?

Comment: The sequence is countable, $\Omega$ is uncountable, so there exists some point in $\Omega$ not in the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Just choose any $a\in \Omega$ that is not in your sequence, i.e. $a\neq z_i$ for all $i$. Since $a$ is not a cluster point, we have that there is $r>0$ with $B(a,r)$ not intersecting any of the $z_i$.